# Simple snippet of ListView and getView

Tags: java, android, listview

I want a simple snippet of a `ListView` which is composed of items taken from a dataset array which also makes use of `getView()` method. `ListView` only contains text entries unlike text and images both.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" />
```

@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        WeatherHolder holder = null;

```
    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new WeatherHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (WeatherHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Weather weather = data[position];
    holder.txtTitle.setText(weather.title);

    return row;
}
```

Comment: this doesnot include the getview() method for textview item font changing

Comment: @user1979237 You could easily extend `ArrayAdapter` to provide the `getView()` method. Please revise your question so that we can give a more appropriate (and *specific*) answer.